# Spring Batch conditional flow causing job exit status failed

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am having problems with a spring batch flow that does the following (simplified)

1. execute a step (always)
2. at runtime decide on what to do next (jobexecutiondecider)
3. if the decider determines to "continue"-> execute a more complex innerflow
4. if the decider determines to "completed" -> do not execute the innerflow but simply complete the job

Given the following MVE:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchExample {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job exampleJob() {
        final FlowBuilder<Flow> innerFlowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<>("innerFlow");
        final Flow innerFlow = innerFlowBuilder
            .start(dummyStep("first innerflow step"))
            .next(dummyStep("second innerflow step"))
            .next(dummyStep("last innerflow step"))
            .build();

        final FlowBuilder<Flow> outerFlowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<>("outerFlow");
        final Flow outerFlow = outerFlowBuilder
            .start(dummyStep("always execute me"))
            .next(decide()).on("CONTINUE").to(innerFlow)
            .from(decide()).on("COMPLETED").end("COMPLETED")
            .build();

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exampleJob")
            .start(outerFlow)
            .end()
            .build();
    }

    private Step dummyStep(String arg) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step_" + arg)
            .tasklet(dummyTasklet(arg))
            .build();
    }

    private Tasklet dummyTasklet(String arg) {
        return new DummyTasklet(arg);
    }

    private DummyDecider decide() {
        return new DummyDecider();
    }

    class DummyTasklet implements Tasklet {

        private final String arg;

        DummyTasklet(String arg) {
            this.arg = arg;
        }

        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("hello from dummy tasklet: " + arg);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
    }

    class DummyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

        @Override
        public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
            final Random random = new Random();
            final int i = random.nextInt();

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                return new FlowExecutionStatus("CONTINUE");
            } else {
                return FlowExecutionStatus.COMPLETED;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

When executing the code, the "continue" flow goes well, but the "completed" flow always exit with a failed job status.

```
 Job: [FlowJob: [name=exampleJob]] completed with the following
 parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]
```

How do I make the job finish with status COMPLETED? In other words, what have I done wrong with the coding of flow?

The code can be run with a spring boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FlowApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FlowApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private Job exampleJob;
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;


    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        jobLauncher.run(exampleJob, new JobParameters());
    }
}
```

**Edit**

When implementing the suggested answer:

```
final Flow outerFlow = outerFlowBuilder
            .start(dummyStep("always execute me"))
            .on("*").to(decide())
            .from(decide()).on("CONTINUE").to(innerFlow)
            .from(decide()).on("COMPLETED").end("COMPLETED")
            .build();
```

And forcing the decider to "CONTINUE":

```
class DummyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {
        @Override
        public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
            return new FlowExecutionStatus("CONTINUE");
        }
    }
```

the innerflow is not being started anymore:

```
Executing step: [step_always execute me]
hello from dummy tasklet: always execute me
Job: [FlowJob: [name=exampleJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]
Job: [FlowJob: [name=exampleJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=0, version=3, name=step_always execute me, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
Job: [FlowJob: [name=exampleJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `outerFlow` should be defined as follows:

```
final Flow outerFlow = outerFlowBuilder
        .start(dummyStep("always execute me"))
        .on("*").to(decide())
        .from(decide()).on("CONTINUE").to(innerFlow)
        .from(decide()).on("COMPLETED").end("COMPLETED")
        .build();
```

I tested this with your example (Thank you for the MVE!) and the job does not fail when the decider returns `COMPLETED`.

The reason is that without routing all outcomes of the `dummyStep("always execute me")` step to the decider with `.on("*").to(decide())`, the flow definition is not correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the fast help. The execution of the "COMPLETED" flow is going correctly and indeed does not fail, however now the innerflow is not working anymore.
 
`Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=0, version=3, name=step_always execute me, 
 Job: [FlowJob: [name=exampleJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]`

Running the program several times shows this unwanted behaviour. @Mahmoud-ben-hassine any ideas of what might be going wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: That's the normal behaviour. A step can't be restarted unless it is marked as restartable. So you need to make the step as restartable.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the same Instance of decider in your flow. I had similar issues and solved them this way.
Instead of calling decide() several times, create just one Decider-Object and re-use it in the outerFlowBuilder:

```
JobExecutionDecider decider = decide();
...
.from(decider).on("CONTINUE").to(innerFlow)
.from(decider).on("COMPLETED").end("COMPLETED")
...
```